# generate regex to match strings

Tags: java, regex, match

i want a regex that can matche:

https://share.host.com/

https://media.host.com/

https://lost.host.com/

https://found.host.com/

https://anything.host.com/

So basically i want the regex to match https://*.host.com/

Note: Am not asking for some website that can generate the regex and am not asking how to generate it neither am asking to learn how to generate regex. I just need the answer from anybody who is experienced in regex matching.

Comment: It doesn't look that complex to write so you probably attempted to do so. What problem ware you facing while writing your solution?

Comment: @Pshemo i don't know how to write regex and i need a fast solution since i have no time to sit and learn regex while am in a hurry to apply a hotfix, beside that i tried all the websites and didn't get any result, i was just asking for some help and maybe i will learn regex after applying the hotfix. but users rained me with down votes and reports. It's a simple help chill out everybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
https://[\w]+[.]host[.]com/
```

Here,

`https://`   - Will match the exact word

`[\w]+`   - will match any word characters [A-Za-z_0-9]

`[.]host[.]com/` - will match the exact word

Below is the Java code,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("https://share.host.com/",
            "https://media.host.com/","https://lost.host.com/","https://anything.google.in/","https://found.host.com/","https://anything.host.com/","https://anything.host.in.com/");

    String regEx="https://[\\w]+[.]host[.]com/";

    for(String input:list) {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regEx).matcher(input);            

        if(matcher.matches()) {         
            System.out.println("Valid   :" +input );
        }else {
            System.out.println("Invalid :" +input);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "[/w*] // - will match any word characters [A-Za-z_]"  and ".host.com/ - will match the exact word" are incorrect. Please pay more attention to your answers. Don't lower credibility of this site which was build by many for years.

Comment: Typo error. made necessary changes

Comment: Nope, it still has many problems in it. First check your solution, then post it.

Comment: @Pshemo Current Expression **https://[\w]+.host.com/** will work for sure

Comment: Test it against `http://somehostecom/` or `http://somehost.com/`.

Comment: Both are invalid.

Comment: My mistake, I change `http` to `https` in my examples and then test again.

Comment: You can't use neither a slash (/) nor dot (.) characters just like that, then need to be escaped. Something like this should work better: `https:\/\/[\w]+\.host\.com\/`

Comment: Made the change. Thank you :)

Comment: @Amongalen In JavaScript regex is in form `/regex/flags` but that is not the case in Java so `/` is not special character which requires escaping here.

Comment: @DeepakGunasekaran Finally :) BTW you don't need to place `\w` in character class. `\w+` has same effect as `[\w]+`. `[\w]` is used if you want to combine it with other characters or character classes, like `[\w!?]` to match alphabetics, numerics, `_`, `!`, `?`.

Comment: @Pshemo I have been using https://regexr.com/ to test that regex and it gave me errors when using unescaped `/`. However, you are correct, it's more of a warning - "this may cause issues if copying/pasting into code"

Comment: Understood @Pshemo Thank you :)